# Certificate for the proxy server for HTTPS traffic

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I am making the proxy server. The problem with HTTPS connections. I found that I need to generate the certificate for each host and put it to Trusted Root.

But for example Fiddler uses only one certificate for all connections. Maybe it generates selft-signed, but don't install to the Trusted Root.

Maybe I can download the certificate from the server and use it to speak with a browser?

Installing and uninstalling certificates takes a bit long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your root-CA certificate to sign the server certificate of the server you are spoofing. As long as the root-CA certificate is valid and trusted by your browser, your browser should not throw any errors. So you need your browser to trust only your root-CA certificate and not every server spoofed certificate.